# How can I set the subdomain to subfolder without changing the display URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

After loading subdomain.domain.com/folders, the user should read the contents of the domain.com/subdomain/folders folder on the server without changing the current URL

User Load URL:

```
subdomain.domain.com/folder
```

File load url:

```
domain.com/subdomain/folder
```

OR (it doesn't matter)

```
subdomain.domain.com/subdomain/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague because of your wording. I *assume* you do not actually have folders called "subdomain.example.com" and "example.com" in your server side file system, but that you refer to the URLS `https://subdomain.example.com/folder` and `https://example.com/subdomain/folder`?

In that case this should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.])\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [END]
```

In case "subdomain" refers to a *specific* name you can simplify the rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [END]
```

Both approaches will perform an *internal* rewrite, so it is further assumed here that both http hosts ("subdomains") are served by the same http server (as "virtual hosts" or by a "fallback virtual host").

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).